# Clubbing FORTRAN and C through changing the makefile

Tags: c, makefile, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a FORTRAN code which calls a C routine to calculate a measure. The FORTRAN code is:

```
program fortran
implicit none
interface
double precision function fpli_hv(A, d, n)
real :: A(5,3)
integer :: d, n
end function fpli_hv
end interface
real :: A(5,3)
double precision :: HV
integer :: i, j
A(1,:) = (/1.1,3.2,2.0/)
A(2,:) = (/6.3,5.2,7.2/)
A(3,:) = (/3.3,4.4,9.1/)
A(4,:) = (/3.3,5.2,2.1/)
A(5,:) = (/7.6,1.7,4.3/)
HV = fpli_hv(A, 3, 5)
end program fortran
```

The c function looks like this:

```
double fpli_hv(double *front, int d, int n, double *ref);
```

In order to club c and fortran, I need to include a Makefil.lib in my makefile. I did so, and prepared my makefile as follows:

```
# The makefile should contain a set of suffix rules. All suffixes must
# be defined. In this case we will have .o for object files, .c for
# C files, and .f for Fortran files.
.SUFFIXES: .o .c .f90

# LIBRARY:
LIBHV = /gpfs0/home/shafiiha/programs/hv-2.0rc1-src/fpli_hv.a
#include Makefile.lib

# Define the C and Fortran compilers to be used in this makefile:
CC=
FC=gfortran -ffree-form -c

# Define flags to be used by the C and Fortran compilers:
CFLAGS =    
FFLAGS =

# Define include to be used by the C and Fortran compilers:
C_INCLUDES =     
F_INCLUDES = fortran.f90

# The linker executable in this case must be the MPI Fortran compiler
# to build a mixed C and Fortran MPI code:
LINK = gfortran

# Define values of parameters that appear in the source codes:
DEFINES =

# Define the list of object files for the linker. The linker will use
# those files to build the executable.
OBJECTS = fortran.o

# The rule that makes the drv executable (note that libraries have
# been specified by the mpif90 linker):
fortran: $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LINK) -o fortran $(OBJECTS) $(LIBHV)

# The rule that makes all object files from C sources:
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $<

# The rule that makes all object files from Fortran sources:
.f90.o:
    $(FC)  $(FFLAGS)  $(F_INCLUDES) $^ $(LIBHV)

# The rule for deleting object files no longer needed after using
# make for drv:
clean:
    rm  *.o
```

But when I make it, I get this message:

```
gfortran -o fortran fortran.o /gpfs0/home/shafiiha/programs/hv-2.0rc1-src/fpli_hv.a  
fortran.o: In function `MAIN__':  
fortran.f90:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to `fpli_hv_'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [fortran] Error 1
```

Could you please help me why I get this error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are going to make a habit of mixing Fortran and C (and there's no reason you shouldn't) then it's worth getting to grips with the 'interoperability with C' features of the recent Fortran standards.  These features provide, inter alia, a standard approach to resolving differences in the ways that C and Fortran compilers have traditionally mangled names.  No more need to figure out how many underscores to append to C names to make them comprehensible to Fortran, and much more besides.

Comment: The makefile that you show us doesn't define a value for the C compiler `CC`, and has the line that includes `Makefile.lib` commented out.

Answer (score 5):

In this era the best way to call C from Fortran is to use the ISO C Binding.   Your problem is the name mangling that Fortran does by default to avoid collisions with routines of C or standard libraries, typically adding underscores.  With the ISO C Binding you can both specify the exact name of the called routine, overriding name mangling, and easily achieve Fortran-C consistency on the arguments.   On the Fortran side you write an interface describing the C routine.   There have been previous answers here and there are examples in the gfortran manual.  The examples aren't unique to gfortran since the ISO C Binding is part of the Fortran 2003 language standard.

Comment: The naming convention is not the only problem - the calling convention is the bigger one actually. All (should be) soved by the ISO C binding.

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing interfaces already (which is great!) then you may as well use the iso_c_binding module which the newest versions of most fortran compilers already have to avoid worrying about underscores and letter cases and what have you:

```
interface
  function fpli_hv(A, d, n) bind(C)
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   real(kind=c_double) :: fpli_hv
   integer(kind=c_int), value :: d, n
   real(kind=c_float) :: A(5,3)

  end function fpli_hv
end interface
```

Comment: My problem is still unsolved, even after embedding C Binding. The point is that there is .h file associated with the c subroutine, and I think it should be handled through "include makefile.lib". But I still get the same error message. What is the problem with my makefile?

Comment: To control the name mangling it should be: bind (C, name="fpli_hv")

Answer (score 0):

Wrap

```
double fpli_hv(double *front, int d, int n, double *ref);
```

with

```
void FPLI_HV_(double *front, int* d, int* n, double *ref, double* returnvalue);
```

Fortran objects only understand things ending in _ and all function passes are by pointer.

(Edit for below comment).

Comment: Actually it is `void fpli_hv_(double* out, double *front, int* d, int* n, double *ref)`. Fortran routines pass the address of the return value location last onto the stack. As to the underscore, YMMV, and you may have to put the name in all caps: `FPLI_HV` or `FPLI_HV_`, depending on teh implementation.

Comment: `gfortran` certainly does not put symbol names in all caps.

Comment: I still have the same problem! Actually, there is a header file too, and the connection between header and source is defined in makefile.lib which I included in my makefile. Why do I still get the same error message?